# C++, How do get this function to delete the string stored in the array?

Tags: c++

I have a delete function that is supposed to delete a string in an array by writing over it with the previous strings. 
The look function see's that Overide matches and should be deleted. But the code i wrote for the loop in Delete is not removing that first spot in the array that Overide has taken up, and the output remains unchanged.
 Also each phrase after + is being added into the array so four spots are taken in the array, and sorry i could not make that part look better the formatting screwed it up.

```
int AR::Look(const std::string & word)
{
    int result = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<counter; ++i)
    {
        if( con[i].find(word) != std::string::npos)
            result = i;
    }
    return result;
}

void AR::Delete(const string & word)
{
    int loc = Look(word);

    if (loc == -1)
    {
         cout<<"word not found\n";
    }
    else
    {
         for(int i=0; i<counter-1,i++;)
         {
             con[i]= con[i+1];
         }
    }
}    



AR their

    Ar(1);
        theirAr + "Overload the +" + " operator as a member function " + "with chaining to add a string " + "to an Arrary object.";

        cout<<theirAr<<endl<<endl;


        cout<<"testing Delete and Look.  <<endl;

        theirAr.Delete("XXXXXX");
        theirAr.Delete("Overload");
        cout<<"Output after Delete and Look called\n";
        cout<<theirArray<<endl<<endl;
```

Comment: Add the declarations too (i.e. header file .h).  Specifically, it'd be more helpful if you included the member variables

Comment: You, like many posters here on SO, need to learn how to debug. Here's a decent post: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/28767/

Answer (score 0):

You are locating the String but only use the value to write an error if it does not appear; if you find the string at pos N you will delete the first string anyway:

```
void AR::Delete(const string & word)
{
    int loc = Look(word);

    if (loc == -1)
    {
        cout<<"word not found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<counter-1,i++;)  <--- Why don't you use loc here???
        {
            con[i]= con[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your `Look` method would be better returning after the first match:

```
for ... {
 if( con[i].find(word) != std::string::npos)
     return i;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Oh, and of course that "deletion" of yours will duplicate the last word each time (because you make `con[i] = con[i+1]` but do not delete `con[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but shouldn't this be like so?

```
void AR::Delete(const string & word)
{
    int loc = Look(word);

    if (loc == -1)
    {
         cout<<"word not found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=loc;i<counter-1,i++;)  // changes in this line
        {
           con[i]= con[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Start at where you found the string and start shuffling them backwards. Also, what shortens the array? i.e. drops the last element off. Looks like that is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
int AR::Look(const std::string & word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    {
        if (con[i].find(word) != std::string::npos)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void AR::Delete(const string & word)
{
    int loc = Look(word);

    if (loc == -1)
    {
         cout << "word not found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         for (int i = loc+1; i < counter; ++i)
         {
             con[i-1] = con[i];
         }
         --counter;
    }
}
```